# How to change attachment size limit in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: team-foundation-server

How does one configure the size limit for Work Item attachments in MS Team Foundation Server 2010?

I remember in 2008 there is a web service, but that same path does not seem to work.

EDIT:
I found...
http://localhost:8080/tfs/_tfs_resources/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/ConfigurationSettingsService.asmx?op=SetMaxAttachmentSize

But it generates TF53010: saying that this must be done in a project collection that is usually found in the root under _tfs_resources. (Which is where I was running this from).

Answer (score 1):

The correct URL for changing the max attachment size for work item attachments is...

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs/<CollectionName>/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/ConfigurationSettingsService.asmx?op=SetMaxAttachmentSize
```

where  is the name of the tfs collection that you want to make the change to.

The error mentioned above seems somewhat missleading because it implies that _Tfs_Resource is the correct path. When browsing IIS, _tfs_resource is the only directory with the configuration page.